# Is there a js function that scrolls a site left right up and down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone knows if there was a javascript or something that scrolls a site left right up and down on a click.

For example I want to create a site with multiple divs. Look at photo below.

[image]

I want each div to fit to screen and div 1 being the main div, the starting point. Say that I had a link in the menu for biography and the content for biography was in div 4 and someone click biography, I want the site to move down to div 3 and then right to div 4 and the same thing goes for div 4 and all the divs. When someone clicks a link in the divs I want the site to scroll in a direction I specify, is this possible.

Left Right Up Down

Answer (score 1):

The jquery animate function is the right way.

Here you can find a simple and clear tutorial on how to use it: http://gazpo.com/2012/03/horizontal-content-scroll/

The tutorial is for horizontal scroll only, but you can easily extend to scroll your page in both directions (vertical and horizontal at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are:

1. [.scrollLeft()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)
2. [.scrollRight()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can animate the `body`'s `scrollTop` value to scroll up and down:

```
$("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#bio").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

The above code will scroll to the element with the `id` of `#bio`.

In terms of scrolling sideways, I supposed you could use a little trick. Set the body's `overflow-x` to `hidden` to hide anything that overflows to the right of the browser viewport. Then you can adjust the `margin-left` of `body` to "scroll" to the right or left. But, of course, this removes the ability for users to scroll through all of your divs.

```
$("body").animate({
    marginLeft: "-100%"
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery animate function ,it will give you more control

```
  $('#div').animate({
    left: '+=50'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

read more from -
http://api.jquery.com/animate/